# How to use BigQuery to improve Cloud ML training in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-ml

So in GCP, how to use BigQuery to improve Cloud ML training?

I did some research, unfortunately can't find exact answer.

cheers,

Comment: I think you can use BigQuery machine learning service to create some predictive models on dataset and evaluate it.

Comment: You should be more specific about "improve". Do you want BigQuery feeds data more easily to Cloud ML to train a model? Or do you want BigQuery to organize your current Cloud ML training set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigQuery with simple SQL queries to train your Machine Learning models. But before you start using read the [introduction](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-intro) so you will be able to understand it better.
Start using BigQuery is very easy you can follow the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-web-ui-start).